# Titanium New install: LiveView is not reloading and Incomplete Code completion list

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I finally broke down and bought a brand new Macbook on Monday and I am starting off with a complete install of everything. I am having two weird issues.

1. Live view will reload one or two times before it hangs at :

   ```
   [LiveView] Reload Triggered 
   REASON: File Changed
   FILE: /Users/Michael/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/......
   ```
2. Code completion is not entirely working in xml, tss or js. For example, after creating `<>` in an xml file, the list does not show View, Button... ect. In TSS there is nothing. In JS it only shows the variables I have already created.

Comment: Congrats on the new Macbook! ;) Rg. LiveView: What NodeJS version are you using? Rg. CC: the first time this might take a while. If that's not the issue. Could you check Help > Studio > View Log File and scroll all the way down (soon after you ran into it) to see if there's errors there?

Comment: @Fokke, I think we are missing something in here as in Point no. 2 Marqui has mentioned that *after creating <> in an xml file*....I think it shows the list of UI elements only when we press < as this less than sign automatically creates its closing (greater than) sign and then after 1-2 seconds it shows the list of UI elements.... Same is for JS file, it really shows the variables once after we create them....Or am I not getting Marqui's point no. 2 correctly :) ?

Comment: I have the exact same problems mentioned above. Same console messages. Studio log shows nothing. Node v. 5.5.0. TiSDK 5.5.1 GA

Comment: Is there any command I can use to manually trigger a LiveView reload?